# If John does ten pushups, does that mean he does nine reps?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, abbreviations

When talking about pushups, we know the word **rep** comes from **repetition**.
But is **rep** really the same as **repetition** in this context?

If John does ten pushups, he does nine repetitions, plus the first pushup, right?
Does that mean he does nine reps?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: "rep" is a clipping of the word *repetition*. Using the shortening of a word doest not change its meaning.

Comment: The *pushup* is the exemplar, the abstract idea of the exercise.  If John does 10 pushups he does 10 reps (instances) of the exemplar. You seem to delight in this kind of question, if memory serves.

Comment: When exercising, the first one counts as a rep. Even if you do just one, it’s still _one rep_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *rep* is short for *repetition*, and yes *rep* is the same as *repetition* in the given example. However, the *definition* of repetition in the example is not the same as the "usual" one (the one I think you're thinking of).
Consider the following definitions:

> [repetition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repetition)
>
> 1. a :  the act or an instance of repeating or being repeated
>      b :  a motion or exercise (such as a push-up) that is repeated and usually counted
>
> (M-W)

In the sense of 1a, yes, the first one is not a repetition, but the following nine pushups are. However, in weightlifting, *rep* and *repetition* often mean 1b. In the sense of 1b, the first pushup is also a *rep* or *repetition* even though it's not repeating a previous instance. So if John does ten *reps*, he does *ten* pushups. Similarly, if he does ten pushups, he does ten reps, not nine.

Here are two more excerpts:

> - [rep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rep)
>     (in bodybuilding) a repetition of a set of exercises.
>     ‘complete all reps on one leg and then change over’
>     (ODO)
> - [**Weight Training: How Many Reps (and Sets) to Do**](http://www.dummies.com/health/exercise/weights/weight-training-how-many-reps-and-sets-to-do/)
>     You can’t design a strength-training (or weight-training) program without knowing two terms: rep and set. Rep (repetition) is one complete motion of an exercise. A set is a group of consecutive repetitions. For example, you can say, “I did two sets of ten reps on the chest press.” This means that you did ten consecutive chest presses, rested, and then did another ten chest presses.
>     (Dummies.com)

This usage is definitely idiomatic in the realm of weightlifting, but it might not be so natural in other circumstances.